# Error trying to run wkhtml on loading libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file

Tags: centos, package

I have Centos 6.6  and I installed `wkhtmltopdf`  package to convert html to pdf,

When I try to create Pdf form Html I see 
`wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director`

So I try to install with `yum install libjpeg` but it told me `Package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`.

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because the different of version `libjpeg` and `wkhtmltopdf` So try you use the same version of both resolve problem,I try use `64 bit` version of both.

Comment: how can I check which versions of both are installed on my system

Comment: @ShubhamGarg `libjpeg -v` and  `wkhtmltopdf --version`, 
usually `--version` or `version` works.